# loop, python, define a series of variables and functions

Tags: python, loops

I am new to Python and have difficulties to understand how to use loop.

could anyone help me how to write below code in a loop/list, which will be much shorter?

```
def a1(self):
    if aorb1 == 1:
        return texta1
    return textb1

def a2(self):
    if aorb2 == 1:
        return texta2
    return textb2

def a3(self):
    if aorb3 == 1:
        return texta3
    return textb3
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you trying to generate the functions in a loop?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve? This will help us to transform your code into a loop.

Comment: yes. I am trying to generate the functions in a loop. is it possible? I am really new to python. I am trying to do the same thing to different series of variables. instead of writing each function down, is there a way to use loop so that I only have to write once? thanks

Comment: Yes, it is totally possible. What have you tried?

Comment: I suspect you don't actually need to generate functions, and are just using that to solve a simpler problem that could use dictionaries or lists. Posting some context (more of your code) could help us decipher what you actually need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can take a stab at what direction you are going and provide some level of guidance, but I suspect that I won't go the correct direction without more information.

First off, you don't need `self` as a parameter.  That only applies to objects.

Next, you do need to provide the variables used within the function as parameters.  It looks like you tried to use `a` and `b` without declaring them.

```
def a1(a, b)
    if a == 1:
        return texta
    elif b == 1:
        return textb
```

Be careful that you don't miss any cases.  What if `a = 0` and `b = 0`?  Then this function would return `None`.

Finally, I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do with the loop, but perhaps something like this?

```
# assign a and b values somewhere
a = 1
b = 0

# save the functions in a list
my_functions = [a1, a2, a3]

# execute each function with the parameters `a` and `b`
for f in my_functions:
    result = f(a, b)
    x.append(result)
```

This will result in a list containing the results of your function executions with parameters `a` and `b`.  Would like to help more, but we need more information.  Perhaps the above will stimulate that.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate lambdas where you pass `a` and `b`, as follows:

```
my_funcs = []
for i in range(1,4):
    func = lambda a, b: textas[i] if a == 1 or b == 1 else textbs[i]
    my_funcs.append(func)
```

You can call such a function like this:

```
my_funcs[0](0,1)  # this does the same as your function a1
```

I don't know what you want `texta1` or `textb1` to be. This could be stored in a dictionary, like I do in the example above.

Comment: Generating a function in a loop is trivial in Python.